# Textbox disappears by mutliplie seaborn distplot's

Tags: python, for-loop, textbox, seaborn, try-except

as an non-coder,I want to visualize distplots with seaborn and a for-loop and also add a textbox with the value of Skew of the data.

Some of the data are floats, so I need to convert them to int (Try and Except-Part), to finally calculate the skew.

After I did this, the textbox doesn`t appear in my subplot. In the first distplot everything is alright, but after the second distplot the textbox disappear.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import skew
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for col in dataset.columns:
    try:
        skew=skew(dataset[col])
    except TypeError:
        skew=pd.DataFrame(dataset[[col]].values.astype(int)).skew()
    finally:
        textstr = 'Skew: %.2f' % (skew, )
            
        ax.text(0.05, 0.95, textstr, transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=14,
                    verticalalignment='top', bbox=props)
        
        ax=  sns.distplot(dataset[col],
                    hist_kws=dict(edgecolor="black", linewidth=1),bins=33)

        props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='wheat', alpha=0.5)
        
        plt.title("Histogram \""  +  str(col) + "\"", fontsize=18)
        plt.xlabel("Werte von \"" + str(col) + "\"", fontsize=16)
        plt.ylabel('Dichte', fontsize=16)

        plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why is `props` defined after its use instead of before? It is used in `ax.text(..., bbox=props)` but only defined 5 lines later. You also have a problem with your variable `ax`: it gets redefined in `ax = sns.distplot(...)`. You can solve things using `sns.distplot(....., ax=ax)` and also moving `ax.text(...)` after the line with `props = dict(...)`

Comment: Thx, that was the little nudge in the right direction, that I needed... I only copied code parts from other different code...in consequence the order of the code was the problem... ...